# how to broadcast my cam to my server and then to another rtmp server

Tags: node.js, camera, broadcast

```
Hello, I am looking for a way to forward my live stream from my server to another server, for example, Facebook via rtmp.

the structure would be something like:

My cam -> my server -> other server rtmp -> viewers

My intention is to capture the transmission and forward it to many rtmp servers to consume the server's resources and not the client's resources, I don't have much knowledge in video transmissions, if it is possible to do it via nodejs it would be great, thanks
```

I have searched for SFU and other ways that are possible, but I want to have several alternatives and find the most ideal to implement it in production

Answer (score 0):

I never did it myself, so I can't recommend the best way to do it.

After some research, if you want to stay with nodejs, I personallly recommend [Mediasoup](https://mediasoup.org/).
It is a powerfull SFU developed in c++ which provided really good bindings with nodejs. All the heavy process is done in c++ and the nodejs API call a child process where the c++ mediasoup worker runs on it. You only have to care about the nodejs API nothing else.

With mediasoup it should not be too difficult to get your stream on the nodejs server.
After that, for transmitting you stream to a rtmp server, it seems you can call ffmpeg in a child process to transfer it from your nodejs server to a rtmp server.

---

I found two github projects with this kind of approach.

[The first one](https://github.com/tan-tan-kanarek/mediasoup-server) is a bit outdated, using an old mediasoup version but maybe you can find something interesting. Specially for the client/browser part, you have an HTML file that should be helpfull. Be aware the API for Mediasoup may have changed, both the front and the back.

EDIT : The first project does not use Mediasoup client library, you can look at it [here](https://github.com/versatica/mediasoup-client)

[The second](https://github.com/bobjiang1988/mediasoup-rtmp-gist) is more recent and really seems to match your need, maybe you will need some cutomization. But they don't provide any front end part.

---

For mediasoup, you will find a lot of ressources over the internet, github, youtube for the client/server part.

If you want to look at it, the [installation guide](https://mediasoup.org/documentation/v3/mediasoup/installation/) for the Mediasoup v3 (last) version. You have to install a python specific version and set few environment variables. After that you can install the npm package and happy coding !

It is easier to install on linux, so if you are on windows, preferably use WSL2 for testing. I don't know anything about Mac, but I know docker is possible, so should be good too.

---

A lot simpler option to stream your webcam to other servers will be to use [OBS studio](https://obsproject.com/), but you must have already considered it
They have a plug in that permits to send your stream to multiple platform at once, looks really cool ! [Here](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/obs-studio-stream-to-multiple-platforms-or-channels-at-once.932/)

Hope it can give you some more options !